# Can you checkout a file from future commit with git?

Tags: git

**Background**: We have just discovered a recently created bug in our code (it was not always there). We did not have an automated test. We have just created one. We have also committed a few more changes after that so the test is not at `HEAD` of `master`.

I want to know if I go back, say 30 commits, can I somehow get this newly created test into my working directory? That way I can run a `git bisect` and have the automated test run instead of manually checking it for each iteration. I figured I could checkout the test commit and `reset --mixed` to get the file into my working directory without being in the index, but I wanted to know if there is an easier way for when you add tests *after* the fact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can use `git checkout <revision> -- path/to/file` to checkout a specific commit's version of a file.

Comment: I actually tried this before asking and it didn't seem to work. I must've mistyped something because now it's doing the trick. You do not get tab completion with git bash on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're just bug-hunting, you may consider simply rewriting history (in a new branch) for the purposes of finding the bug.

You can `git rebase -i <most recent working commit>`, insert the commit that adds the test right after the working commit, and have rebase write the tests into all of your history. Then you can bisect safely.

If you want to just check the tests out "from the future" be sure to limit the bisection to before you added the tests, or `git` will complain about adding the test files.